# Recording Audio with OpenAL

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I've been comparing various audio libraries available in C++. I was wondering, I'm kind of stuck starting with OpenAL. Can someone point out an example program how to record from a mic using OpenAL in C++.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Last time I checked OpenAL it was quite simple.  You create the recording device and start the recording going.  You then just call the get buffer function.  It will wait until there is enough data to fill the buffer and then return when there is enough data.

Why not just look at the "capture" example that comes with the OpenAL SDK ...?

Comment: That would be a file called testcapture.c, if you're looking at the OpenAL source code.

Answer (score 30):

Open the input device and start recording using alcCaptureStart and fetch the sample using alcCaptureSamples

```
#include <OpenAL/al.h>
#include <OpenAL/alc.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SRATE = 44100;
const int SSIZE = 1024;

ALbyte buffer[22050];
ALint sample;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    alGetError();
    ALCdevice *device = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, SRATE, AL_FORMAT_STEREO16, SSIZE);
    if (alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR) {
        return 0;
    }
    alcCaptureStart(device);

    while (true) {
        alcGetIntegerv(device, ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, (ALCsizei)sizeof(ALint), &sample);
        alcCaptureSamples(device, (ALCvoid *)buffer, sample);

        // ... do something with the buffer 
    }

    alcCaptureStop(device);
    alcCaptureCloseDevice(device);

    return 0;
}
```