# Capture Audio in C++

Tags: c++, audio-recording

I'm starting to develop an application that involves dealing with recording audio. I'm using C++ (with Visual Studio, but trying to avoid .NET specific libraries) and I was wondering where would be the best place to start? Are there recommended libraries out there?

If it matters, I'm currently just working with the line in on my computer - no special sound hardware considered (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest OpenAL! I have used it in numerous game projects to play audio and it is just as capable for recording sound.

Check out this stack overflow answer for more information: [Recording Audio with OpenAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056113/recording-audio-with-openal)