# Open Al recording and playing back audio - C++

Tags: c++, openal

Im trying to record audio with open al, and then save the file and then play it back.

I have searched the web for 5 hours without any luck in finding an example.

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

there is an example at this
web location that works with linux.
 but if your big on win, or apple. you will need
too hack it a little more.
[Recording Audio with OpenAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056113/recording-audio-with-openal?rq=1)