# Recording sound with OpenAL(C++). Buffer size

Tags: c++, audio, microphone, openal

I have one problem with recording sound with OpenAL library. I read second answer on this question: [Recording Audio with OpenAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056113/recording-audio-with-openal) . But I dont understand, how I can change buffer size. If I change SSIZE, and buffer size to, for example, 441, the program is crashing. If you know answer of this question, please explain me, how I can get 1 ms buffer with sampling rate 96000Hz. (96 elements in array, with 1 channel, 8bit). Please help me.

Added:
I change this:

```
const int SRATE = 96000;
const int SSIZE = 96;

ALbyte buffer[SSIZE];
ALint sample;
```

and

```
AL_FORMAT_STEREO16
```

to

```
AL_FORMAT_MONO8
```

and this gave me this error:
[image]

Comment: Show the code you've written ... also bear in mind that a 1ms buffer is unlikely to be possible due to overheads

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that the number of samples returned by alcGetIntegerv is larger than SSIZE ...

Comment: After alcGetIntegerv sample value always 0. How I can discover accurate value of disared length of the buffer?